# define include directory path (for *.h) CentOS

Tags: centos, environment-variables, path, libraries

I was reading these questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45106/235247

I'm compiling `gmp`

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/gmp
```

and installing producing three folders.

`include`, `lib` and `share`

In the case, bin

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Custom/SOMEPROGRAM/bin
```

The `lib` folder can be added using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Custom/gmp/lib
```

My question, Is there some *`PATH_VARIABLE`* for `include` different folders (with `*.h` files)?

```
export PATH_VARIABLE=$PATH_VARIABLE:/usr/local/Custom/gmp/include
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `C_INCLUDE_PATH` for C header files or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` for C++ header files or `CPATH` for both

There's more info [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181116065607/https://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html), or read `man gcc`